# display data from pre filled sqlite db in list using ng repeat in ionic framework

Tags: android, angularjs, sqlite, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a beginner. Using ionic 1, i want to display data from a database in a list using ng repeat, the results **not display in the view (html)!!!** (genymotion emulator for android)
I have already tried tutorials, without success.

My code:

Controllers.js

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

$scope.allSessions = [];

$scope.selectAll = function() {

var query = "SELECT * FROM meds";

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {

    if(res.rows.length > 0) {
         console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(0).id + " " + res.rows.item(0).nom);
         for (var i=0; i<res.rows.length; i++) {

            $scope.allSessions.push({
                id: res.rows.item(i).id,
                nom: res.rows.item(i).nom
                })
         }
    } else {
        console.log("No results found");
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.error("error=>"+err);
});
}
```

app.js

```
var Myapp = angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'ngCordova',        'app.controllers']);
var db = null;
Myapp.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
if(window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {

  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
  cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);
}
if(window.StatusBar) {
  StatusBar.styleDefault();
}
window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("med.db",0, function() {
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'med.db', location: 'default'});
    }, function(error) {
        console.error("There was an error copying the database: " + error);
        db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB({name: 'med.db', location: 'default'});
    });
 });
 });
```

meds.html

```
<div>
<ion-list>
<ion-item ng-repeat="session in allSessions" href="#/app/session/{{session.id}}">
<h3>{{session.id}} {{session.nom}}</h3>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
</div>
```

Need help please

Answer (score 0):

Do it:

**Controller.js**

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

$scope.allSessions = [];

$scope.selectAll = function() {

var query = "SELECT * FROM meds";

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {     
    if(res.rows.length > 0) {
       angular.forEach(res.rows, function(item)){
          $scope.allSessions.push({
             id: item.id,
             nom: item.nom
          })
    }

    } else {
        console.log("No results found");
    }
}, function (err) {
    console.error("error=>"+err);
});
}
```

Comment: not work.  Logs ` [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app.controllers due to:
11-24 15:21:16.344 I/chromium( 1730): Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'app.controllers' is not available! You either misspelled...<omitted>...2)", source: file:///android_asset/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (17922)
[INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported
[INFO:async_pixel_transfer_manager_android.cc(60)] Async pixel transfers not supported) `

Comment: This is an injection error. Review your controller and check if you forget something. 
Basicly, you just should get in my code, the part of the angular.forEach, because the rest it´s fine, to me.

Comment: Basicly, you should go throught the res.rows, which have a array of items, and forEach item, we gonna push it on your array called allSessions...

Comment: thanks, it's work with this :.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {
$scope.selectAll = function() {
$scope.items = [];
 var query = "SELECT nom, dci, labo FROM meds";
 $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {
 if (res.rows.length > 0) {
 for (var i = 0; i < res.rows.length; i++) {
 console.log("SELECTED -> " + res.rows.item(i).nom + " " + res.rows.item(i).dci + " " + res.rows.item(i).labo);
  $scope.items.push({
 id: res.rows.item(i).id,
 nom: res.rows.item(i).nom,
   dci: res.rows.item(i).dci,
  ...

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $cordovaSQLite) {

$scope.selectAll = function() {

var query = "SELECT * FROM meds";

$cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, []).then(function(res) {     
if(res.rows.length > 0) {
 $scope.allSessions = [];
  for (var i = 0; i<res.rows.length; i++){
      $scope.allSessions.push({
         id: res.rows.item(i).id,
         nom: res.rows.item(i).nom
      })
 }

 } else {
    console.log("No results found");
 }
 }, function (err) {
console.error("error=>"+err); 
 });
}
```

---

then pass using ng repeat in the view. this should work perfect in 2017.enter code here